# How to use mobile SAM model on flutter app?

Tags: flutter, plugins, onnx, sam

I am going to use mobile SAM model on flutter app side. To do this I am developing flutter plugin that can use onnx file. I have got the ONNX file already. I can use ONNX file on mobile Native code side but I don't know how to use mobile_sam package of python on Native(Kotlin, Swift) code side.
Is there any method to do this? Or should I make native code from the package?

I have made flutter plugin that can use normal onnx file on mobile side. But the mobile SAM model requires *.pt file as well. how to use this *.pt file on mobile native code?

Comment: You could save the model to pytorch lite interpreter. For this there exists a package: https://pub.dev/packages/pytorch_mobile. Pytorch version can't be higher than 1.11 however.